An irrational sequence $ u_{n+1}=\left| u_{n}-u_{n-1}\right| $
I am interested in an extensive study of the sequence defined by
$$  u_{n+1}=\left| u_{n}-u_{n-1}\right| $$
with strictly positive initial values $  u_{0}$ and $u_{1}$.
If  $  u_{0}$ and $u_{1}$ ​ are both integers, the above formula is a (slightly slower) version of the Euclidean GCD algorithm based on subtraction. Once the GCD value is reached, the sequence falls into a periodic three-element loop (GCD,GCD,$0$), which is relatively easy to prove.
If  $  u_{0}$ and $u_{1}$ ​ are rational numbers with at least one non-integer value, the analysis can be reduced to the first case by introducing the common denominator of both initial terms and performing the subtraction operations on the (integer) numerators. This also results in a three-element loop (constant,constant,$0$)
If  $  u_{0}$ and $u_{1}$ ​ are both irrational numbers, but $\dfrac{u_{1}}{u_{0}}$​​ is rational, then this case can similarly be reduced to the previous two.
My question is: what happens when $  u_{0}$ and $u_{1}$​ are both irrational numbers, but $\dfrac{u_{1}}{u_{0}}\notin \mathbb{Q}$   ?
It seems that such a sequence should converge to $0$ (since there is no "common factor"). However, I am unsure how to prove this.
Any suggestions or proofs would be welcome.

Well, if it does converge, it definitely converges to $0,$ since, if $u$ is the limit, then taking the limit of both sides gives $u=|u-u|=0.$  So the question is, does it converge?

In https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2275949/42969 it is shown that each of the sequences $(u_{3k+r})$, $r=0, 1, 2$, is decreasing (and therefore convergent).

Yes, the sequence will decrease to zero as long as $u_1/u_0\not\in\mathbb Q$.
First, we note that, if $u_1/u_0\not\in\mathbb Q$, then, for every $n$, $u_n\neq 0$ and $u_{n+1}/u_n\not\in\mathbb Q$. This is a simple induction on $n$.
We begin by showing that the sequence is weakly decreasing in the following sense: for all $n\geq 0$ we have $u_n\geq u_{n+3}$. This is because
$$u_{n+3}=|u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}|=\big|u_{n+1}-|u_n-u_{n+1}|\big|.$$
If $u_{n+1}\geq u_n$, then $|u_n-u_{n+1}|=u_{n+1}-u_n$, and we have $u_{n+3}=u_n$. Otherwise,
$$u_{n+3}=\big|u_{n+1}-|u_n-u_{n+1}|\big|=\big|2u_{n+1}-u_n\big|;$$
since $u_n>u_{n+1}$, we have $-u_n\leq 2u_{n+1}-u_n<u_n$, and so $|2u_{n+1}-u_n|\leq u_n$.
Now, the sequences $a_n=u_{3n}$, $b_n=u_{3n+1}$, and $c_n=u_{3n+2}$ are all nonincreasing sequences of nonnegative real numbers. So, they tend to limits $a$, $b$, and $c$, which must satisfy $a=|b-c|$, $b=|c-a|$, and $c=|a-b|$. Order these numbers as $x,y,z$ with $x\geq y\geq z\geq 0$. Since $x=|y-z|=y-z\leq y\leq x$, we must have $z=0$ and $x=y$. We conclude that one of $\{a,b,c\}$ is zero and the other two are equal. We'll treat the case where $b=0$; the other two cases are similar. If $a=0$ as well, then we are done; henceforth, we assume $a>0$.
Since $(u_{3n},u_{3n+1},u_{3n+2})\to(a,0,a)$ for some real $a>0$, we must eventually have $2u_{3n+1}<u_{3n},u_{3n+2}$. Let $n_0$ be a threshold so that this holds for all $n\geq n_0$. Then, for all $n\geq n_0$, we have
\begin{align*}
u_{3n+2}&=|u_{3n}-u_{3n+1}|=u_{3n}-u_{3n+1}\\
u_{3n+3}&=|u_{3n+1}-u_{3n+2}|=|u_{3n}-2u_{3n+1}|=u_{3n}-2u_{3n+1}\\
u_{3n+4}&=|u_{3n+2}-u_{3n+3}|=|(u_{3n}-2u_{3n+1})-(u_{3n}-u_{3n+1})|=u_{3n+1}.
\end{align*}
We conclude that $u_{3n+1}=u_{3n+4}$ for all $n\geq n_0$, and thus by induction that $u_{3n+1}=u_{3n_0+1}$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Since $u_{3n+1}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, this implies that $u_{3n_0+1}=0$, contradicting the property that $u_1/u_0\not\in\mathbb Q$.

"Since $\left( u_{3n1}u_{3n+1},u_{3n+2}\right) \rightarrow \left( a,0,a\right)$
for some real $a>0$
, we must eventually have $2u_{3n+1} <u_{3n},u_{3n+2}$"
WHY ??? Could you explain, please?

.....is this a simple $\varepsilon$ manipulation?

@user472228 Yes, something like that. Since $a/3>0$, there exists some $n_0$ for which, for all $n\geq n_0$, we have
$$|u_{3n}-a|,|u_{3n+2}-a|,|u_{3n+1}-0|<\frac a3.$$
In particular, $u_{3n+1}<a/3$ and $u_{3n},u_{3n+2}>a-a/3=2a/3$. This is enough to imply the inequality I stated.

Thank you very much!
